# Send data to a specific user using socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

i have a node js server which uses socket.io to send data to users. So far i can send data to the user that requested it, or all users. But i want to know a way to send data to a specfic user requested from someone else. In this scenario its a website where you can host a game. So when another user wants to join, i want to send data to the person hosting that game telling them this user wants to join. Here is my code

```
exports.Server = Server = function()
{
this.userId = 1;
this.userName = "Guest";
};

Server.prototype.initialise = function(port)
{
//Create the server using the express module
this.server = http.createServer(app);

//Declare the 'public' folder and its contents public
app.use(express.static('public'));  

//Listen to any incoming connections on the declared port and start using websockets
this.server.listen(port);
this.startSockets();
this.em = new events();

consoleLog('SERVER', 'Running on port: ' + port);
};

Server.prototype.startSockets = function()
{
//When a user connects to the server on the 'game' socket
this.socket = io.listen(this.server);

this.socket.of('game').on('connection', function(user)
    {
        //Set their usedId and username
        user.userId = this.userId;
        user.userName = this.userName + " " + this.userId;

        //Increment the user id by 1 so each user with get a unique id
        this.userId++;

        //Send a response back to the client with the assigned username and user id and initialise them
        user.emit('response', user.userId, user.userName);
        this.em.emit('initialiseUser', user.userId, user.userName);

        //Tell the server to log the user that has just connected
        consoleLog('SERVER', user.userName + ' has connected. ID: ' + user.userId)

        //Server listeners from the client

        //If the user wants to host a game, take the game settings they requested
        user.on('hostGame', function(boardSize, gameMode, gameNote)
            {       
                //Tell the app to request a new hosted game with the users information and settings
                this.em.emit('hostGame', user.userId, user.userName, boardSize, gameMode, gameNote);
            }
            .bind(this));

        //If the user wants to cancel the game they are hosting
        user.on('cancelHostGame', function()
            {   
                //Tell the app to request to cancel their game passing in the users information
                this.em.emit('cancelHostGame', user.userId, user.userName);
            }
            .bind(this));

        user.on('joinGame', function(user.id, user.userName, opponentId)
            {                       
                //Need to tell the user with the opponent Id, that the user.id wants to join
            }
            .bind(this));

        //When a user disconnects
        user.on('disconnect', function()
            {   
                //Tell the app to request to cancel the game the user was hosting
                this.em.emit('cancelHostGame', user.userId, user.userName);

                //Tell the server who disconnected
                consoleLog('SERVER', user.userName + ' has disconnected. ID: ' + user.userId)
            }
            .bind(this));
    }
    .bind(this));
```

};

```
function updateGamesList(socket, hostedGames)
{
//Emit the updateGameList function on the client and pass through the array of games being hosted
socket.socket.of('game').emit('updateGameList', hostedGames);
};
```

So u can see when a user clicks join game, it passes the id of the opponent thats hosting the game they want to join. If i do user.emit it will go to the person joining and if i do em.emit it will go to every user on the website. How would i just direct it to a user of that specific id?

Comment: Why did you tag Java?

Comment: mb i was typing too quick, meant javascript

Comment: Do you have another socket dedicated exclusively to messaging?

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue?@Slavik Ribz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send confirmation to host of game,You first have to manage object which contains total games created,and each value of object will contain an array in which there will be objects of users connected to game,So that object structure will look like,

```
var object={};
object={ game1 : [object-user1,object-user2,object-user3],
         game2 : [object-user1,object-user2,object-user3],
         game3 : [object-user1,object-user2,object-user3]
};
```

Now when user creates room its object will be stored in object under room,That can be done as below

```
var object={};
io.on('connection', function(user){
    user.on('createroom',function(game){
        var array=[];
        array[0]=user;
        object[game]=array
        socket.join(data[0]);
        socket.emit('createres', data[0]);
    });
});
```

Now You have an object which contains the game and corresponding array which contains the list of users connected game,Now if you want to send confirmation to host of game you can do as shown below,

```
user.on('joingame',function(game){
    data.game=game;
    data.user=user;
    object[game][0].emit("confirmjoin",data);
});
```

Above code is for server side,In here above code we sending confirmation to user who created game,Here object[game][0] will return first element of array for specific game,So we can call client using that value;

Here is client side code,

```
user.on('confirmjoin',function(data){

    if(//allow user to join){
        user.emit('allowtojoin',data);
    }
});
```

Above code is for client side,In above code if game host wants to allow join for user it will check condition and it will emit to server "allowjoin" sending user object,

Here is server side code for Which it will listen to join game,

```
user.on('allowjoin',function(data){
    data.user.join(data.game);
});
```

Now your server.js file will conatain something like

```js
var object={};
io.on('connection', function(user){
    user.on('createroom',function(game){
        var array=[];
        array[0]=user;
        object[game]=array
        socket.join(data[0]);
        socket.emit('createres', data[0]);
    });
    user.on('joingame',function(game){
        data.game=game;
        data.user=user;
        object[game][0].emit("confirmjoin",data);
    });
    user.on('allowjoin',function(data){
        data.user.join(data.game);
    });
});
```

hope this will help .!